# How would you build for Mac with Cocos2d-v3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

Ideally I would like to have multiple targets in my `XCode` project to build for `Mac` and `iOS`.

I am using `SpriteBuilder`, so I am also interested in compatibility with thing such as `CCBReader`.

I want to build it for Mac so I would be able to debug my game faster.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, SpriteBuilder not support publish target for both iOS and Mac.

This post may help: http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/how-to-create-osx-targets/807